# Came across the following lines of code in NS3. Need help understanding it

Tags: c++, object-oriented-analysis, ns-3

The Node object is declared as

```
class Node : public Object
{
public:
  static TypeId GetTypeId (void);
```

and it's definition is

```
TypeId
Node::GetTypeId (void)
{
  static TypeId tid = TypeId ("ns3::Node")
    .SetParent<Object> ()
    .SetGroupName ("Network")
    .AddConstructor<Node> ()
    .AddAttribute ("DeviceList",
                   "The list of devices associated to this Node.",
                   ObjectVectorValue (),
                   MakeObjectVectorAccessor (&Node::m_devices),
                   MakeObjectVectorChecker<NetDevice> ())
    .AddAttribute ("ApplicationList",
                   "The list of applications associated to this Node.",
                   ObjectVectorValue (),
                   MakeObjectVectorAccessor (&Node::m_applications),
                   MakeObjectVectorChecker<Application> ())
    .AddAttribute ("Id",
                   "The id (unique integer) of this Node.",
                   TypeId::ATTR_GET, // allow only getting it.
                   UintegerValue (0),
                   MakeUintegerAccessor (&Node::m_id),
                   MakeUintegerChecker<uint32_t> ())
    ;
  return tid;
}
```

My question is regarding this:

```
static TypeId tid = TypeId ("ns3::Node")
    .SetParent<Object> ()
```

Once we declare what `tid` is, there is no end of line `;` symbol and the next few lines start with the dot `.` operator.

```
    .SetParent<Object> ()
    .SetGroupName ("Network")
    .AddConstructor<Node> ()
```

I did a basic study of OOP before starting to work on NS3 but didn't come across this kind of syntax before.

Is it an alternate way of declaring the methods/attributes' of the class `Node`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whitespace, including line breaks, is not meaningful in C++.
`TypeId ("ns3::Node")` creates a temporary object. `.SetParent<Object> ()` is a method called on the object. Apparently, it returns a reference to the object, on which `.SetGroupName()` is called, and so on.

Each method sets some attribute on the temporary object. Once it is fully configured, it is used to initialize `static TypeId tid`.

Comment: So what does it mean when `  .SetParent<Object> ()
    .SetGroupName ("Network")
    .AddConstructor<Node> () ` are written without `;` separating them? As per my understanding, attributes are methods for a class and each of them is normally a function that is defined on their own with no link to the other methods. My answer is more related to the syntax that is being used?

Comment: Each one is defined on their own somewhere, but you don't show where they are defined. You show where they are *called*. This is a normal way of calling a method.